# Propel: how to remove link made via many-to-many relation

Tags: php, symfony1, many-to-many, propel

(link to previous question just in case: [Struggling with one-to-many relation in an admin form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754811/struggling-with-one-to-many-relation-in-an-admin-form))

I have this many-to-many relation in my Symfony-1.3 / Propel-1.4 project between **User** and **Partner**. When the User is being saved, if it has certain boolean flag being true, I want to clear all the links to the partners. Here is what I do at the moment and it doesn't work:

```
// inside the User model class
public function save(PropelPDO $con = null) {
  if ($this->getIsBlaBla()) {
    $this->setStringProperty(NULL);
    $this->clearUserPartners();
  }
  parent::save($con);
}
```

Setting the string property to NULL works; looking at the DB clearly shows it. Thing is however, the USER_PARTNER table still holds the relations between the users and the partners. So I figured I have to clear the links one by one, like this:

```
foreach($this->getUserPartners() as $user_partner) {
  $user_partner->delete();
  //UserPartnerPeer::doDelete($user_partner); // tried that too
}
```

Both don't do the trick.

As I mentioned in my previous question, I am just monkey-learning Symfony via trial and error, so I evidently miss something very obvious. Please point me in the right direction!

**EDIT: Here is how I made it work:**

Moved the code to the Form class, like so:

```
public function doSave(PropelPDO $con = null) {
  parent::doSave($con);

  if ($this->getObject()->getIsSiteOwner()) {
    $this->getObject()->setType(NULL);
    $this->getObject()->save();

    foreach($this->getObject()->getUserPartners() as $user_partner) {
      $user_partner->delete();
    }
  }

  return $this->getObject();
}

public function updateObject($values = null) {
  $obj = parent::updateObject($values);

  if ($obj->getIsSiteOwner()) {
    $obj->clearUserPartners();
  }

  return $this->object;
}
```

What this does is:

- When the boolean flag `is_site_owner` is up, it clear the `type` field and **saves** the object (ashamed I have not figured that out for so long).
- Removes all existing UserPartner many-to-many link objects.
- Clears newly associated (via the DoubleList) UserPartner relations.

Which is what I need. Thanks to all who participated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey so now you have a many-to-many relation where in database terms is implemented into three tables (User , Parter and UserPartner). Same thing happens on Symfony and Propel, so you need to do something like this on the doSave method that should declare in UserForm:

```
public function doSave($con = null)
{
 parent::doSave($con); //First all that's good and nice from propel
 if ($this->getValue('please_errase_my_partners_field'))
 {
  foreach($this->getObject()->getUserPartners() as $user_partner_relation)
  {
   $user_partner_relation->delete();
  }
 }
 return $this->getObject();
}
```

Check the method name "getUserPartners" that should be declared on the BaseUser.class.php (lib/model/om/BaseUser.class.php)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. Sadly though this method is not called at all. Made an experiment for directly nulling given property no matter what is being clicked in the form, but evidently this is the wrong place to touch. :(  Have to add, the real project actually used sfGuardPlugin and my "User" model is actually the "sfGuardUser" from there, but so far this hasn't been a problem.

Comment: Mmm i dont know if thats entirely true, i know for sure that method is called because i have used it in the past. The nullification does not work because the way the relationship is stored. Thrust me on this one! Check the processForm method generated in the action.class.php located on cache

Comment: I did look, didn't notice any trace of my code in this method. Did delete all cache, did regenerate all models/filters/forms, did redeploy, did restart Apache, still the same. Either the doSave is not called at all, or changes made to the object while in it aren't propagated to the DB. Help!

Comment: OK, I obviously messed up something when I tried it. This time it worked. One last thing remained. I also want to null a string field in the "if" block: `$this->getObject()->setType(NULL);` It doesn't get cleared, though. Ideas? Will mark your answer anyway, but this would be a nice bonus still.

Comment: Added an EDIT section in the question. Check for more details.

Comment: I finally made it work. Had to add a few things, but marking your answer as THE answer because you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @dimitko sorry for the delais and problems, it's quite conforting that i was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning Symfony, I suggest you use Doctrine instead of Propel because, I think Doctrine is simplier and more "beautiful" than Propel.

For your problem, I think you are on the good way. If I were you, I will keep my function `save()` I will write an other function in my model User

```
public function clearUserPartners(){
    // You have to convert this query to Propel query (I'm sorry, but I don't know the right syntax)
    "DELETE FROM `USER_PARTNER` WHERE user_id = '$this->id'"
}
```

With this function, you don't must use a PHP foreach.

But I don't understand what is the attribute `StringProperty`...

Comment: Well, in my scenario it was a "TYPE" => "$this->setType(NULL)". Wrote it like that just to show that nulling a string worked, while clearing the many-to-many relation didn't.

Comment: I dont think that "simplier and more beautiful" are any good to make a choice between.orms I myself user Propel for my projects and turns out it is quite simple. I do support Doctrine algo because its a more Object Oriented approach to a ORM.

Answer (score 0):

```
UserPartnerQuery::create()->filterByUser( $userObject )->delete();
```

or

```
UserPartnerQuery::create()->filterByUser( $partnerObject )->delete();
```

Had the same problem. This is a working solution.

Comment: Could it be that *Query classes where added in propel 1.5 version?

Comment: If that's the case, no luck for me. Using Propel 1.4 for this project.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that your second solution, ie. looping over the related objects and calling delete() on them should work. It's the documented way of doing things (see : http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/08-Inside-the-Model-Layer#chapter_08_sub_saving_and_deleting_data).

But instead of bombing the DB with delete queries, you could just as well delete them in one go, by adding a method to your Peer class that performs the deletion using a simple DB query.

Comment: As I mentioned, still a Symfony rookie here. Would appreciate you giving some code snippet that could do that. I am sure I can invent it myself, but I would be more confident to experiment if I have an example code.